# Make vim highlight python builtins when they are not followed by a dot

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to highlight built in Python functions in vim *only* when they are preceded by 1 more whitespaces? Furthermore, is there a modular way to do this? That is, I don't want to edit every single `syn keyword pythonBuiltinFunc abs chr ...` line, I just want to be able to say something like `syn keyword pythonBuiltinFunc onlymatchafter="\s+"`?

EDIT:

Here's an example, since the two people who answered my question didn't seem to understand what I was asking which is my fault for not being more clear.

When I write the following Python code

```
import numpy as np
x = np.abs(np.random.randn(10, 10))
```

The word `abs` gets highlighted simply because vim is essentially just matching anything that has the word `abs` in it that is not inside of a  string. How can I get vim to highlight the Python builtins WITHOUT highlighting them when they are preceded by a dot?

Answer (score 0):

The matched text of `:syn keyword` can only be comprised of *keyword characters*; though that set can be configured (`:setlocal iskeyword=...`), it would be foolish to include whitespace in there.

You have two options: Either re-write all keywords with `:syn match` (which can include whitespace), or make all keywords `contained` and define a `:syn region` that only starts after whitespace.

Both are rather huge interventions that basically mean you're (re-)writing your own Python syntax. You haven't told us **why** you'd want that... I'd say it's a bad idea.

Comment: To implement @Ingo's 2nd option, I wrote a patch to the `syntax/python.vim` file shipped by Vim 7.4.  Not neat but seems to work for me.  You can find it at here: https://github.com/congma/vim-syntax-python Feel free to improve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is the reason you want to do this because you want to remind yourself of using a consistent style in Python?

If so, I would like to recommend you adding [the syntastic plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic). In combination with a tool such as [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) it automatically detects and highlights any style errors you wish (by default PEP8 style violations), together with general syntax errors. I use this plugin a lot and highly recommend it.

Comment: No. The reason is because vim highlights any function that has the same name as a built in Python function.